# Azure Spot Instance | gpu-cluster

Tags: azure

I am unable to create nodepool with "Spot" Instance for GPU Cluster.
$kubectl describe node {node-name}

get Under the Capacity section, the GPU should list as **nvidia.com/gpu: 1** for "Standard_NC6" size with -priority Spot --eviction-policy Delete --spot-max-price -1

following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/gpu-cluster

Example:

1.Not Working with  **nvidia.com/gpu: 1**
Cmd:
az aks nodepool add --resource-group {ResourceGroup} --cluster-name {ClusterName} --name {NodePoolName} --priority Spot --eviction-policy Delete --spot-max-price -1 -c 1 -s Standard_NC6 --node-osdisk-size 30

$kubectl describe node {node-name}

Capacity:
attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  12
cpu:                            6
ephemeral-storage:              30309264Ki
hugepages-1Gi:                  0
hugepages-2Mi:                  0
memory:                         115414528Ki
pods:                           110

2.Working  **nvidia.com/gpu: 1**
Cmd:
az aks nodepool add --name gpu --cluster-name {ClusterName}  --resource-group {ResourceGroup} --node-vm-size Standard_NC6 --node-count 1 --aks-custom-headers UseGPUDedicatedVHD=true

$kubectl describe node {node-name}

Capacity:
attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  24
cpu:                            6
ephemeral-storage:              129900528Ki
hugepages-1Gi:                  0
hugepages-2Mi:                  0
memory:                         57584876Ki
nvidia.com/gpu:                 1
pods:                           110